# why my setTimeout function is not work while I use react-native and react-router-native

Tags: reactjs, react-native, redux, react-router, react-redux

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iO4Ri.png)

as you see , I use setTimeout function at componentDismount step, but it just failed and imemediate console.log

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please post your code as text in a code block, NOT a linked image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you run into this when the debugger is used.  React-native has the bug with a timer.

https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/4470

https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/1693

When the debugger is not used all works fine. As you can see in the threads, now we have not any workable solution

Comment: 3Q, I had spent two hours to find out this werid problem but did not get the answer , and now I konw this is not my program fault but the react-native is, I am very happy.